# Can't make use of a link generated by a method within my scraper

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, web-scraping

I'm very new to write and work with classes in python. I've written a parser using class to check whether there is any `next page` url generated by `.get_nextpage()` method. However, when `.get_nextpage()` method produces a link then it should be printed right after `self.get_nextpage(soup)` line in `try except block` within `.get_links()` method. I've got stuck here as to how I can make it possible.

No alternative solution is what I'm after. I just wish to know the logic If I can make a go.

I used `while True` condition within `.get_links()` method so that it will run until the `.get_nextpage()` method generates a new link. (`It's not the part of this question. Just to let you know why I used "while True" there`)

This is the scraper:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping"

class StackOverflowClass(object):

    def __init__(self, link):
        self.url = link

    def get_links(self):
        while True:
            res = requests.get(self.url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

            try:
                self.get_nextpage(soup)
                # what to do here to get the link generated within ".get_nextpage()" method
            except:break

    def get_nextpage(self,sauce):
        nurl = sauce.select_one("div.pager a[rel='next']")
        if nurl:
            link = urljoin(self.url,nurl.get("href"))

crawler = StackOverflowClass(url)
crawler.get_links()
```

To be clearer what I meant, take a look at the following lines once again:

```
try:
    self.get_nextpage(soup)
    # what to do here to get the link generated within ".get_nextpage()" method
except:break
```

Comment: You're not returning anything from `get_nextpage`. did you mean to `return link`?

Comment: Try to add `return link` at the end of `get_nextpage` definition (in `if`  block). Also replace `try: self.get_nextpage(soup)` with `if self.get_nextpage(soup)` and `except: break` with `else: break`

Comment: @Andersson you should repost this as an answer

Comment: I would be very honoured to accept your solution @ sir Andersson. Yes, that was a mistake I didn't return anything. However, `self.url = self.get_nextpage(soup)` within `if else` block was the fix to make it run cyclically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your `get_nextpage` as below:

```
def get_nextpage(self,sauce):
    nurl = sauce.select_one("div.pager a[rel='next']")
    if nurl:
        link = urljoin(self.url,nurl.get("href"))
        return link
```

and then you can use it in `get_links()` to get link value:

```
def get_links(self):
    while True:
        res = requests.get(self.url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

        if self.get_nextpage(soup):
            link = self.get_nextpage(soup)
            # do whatever you want with link
        else:break
```

Note that `if`/`else` is used instead of `try`/`except` as method/function without explicit `return` returns `None` and `try: None` will never generate exception and loop `break` will not be executed

Comment: A minor question about indentation: If I use `return link` one tab left (other than what you did), I get the same result. Which way i should follow? Thanks.

Comment: No. You won't get same result actually. It works while `if nurl` returns `True`, but if it return `False` then `link = self.get_nextpage(soup)` will not be executed and `return link` line will led to `NameError`. But you can do `else: link = ""`. In this case it's OK to move `return link`